# How do I evaluate the Wronskian for this equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, wronskian

Martin Braun - Differential equations and their applications Chapter 2.1 p.137

> Let $y_1,y_2$ be solutions of Bessel's equation $$t^2y'' + ty' + (t^2-n^2)y=0$$ on the interval $(0,\infty)$ with $y_1(1)=1,y_1'(1)=0,y_2(1)=0,y_2'(1)=1$. Compute the Wronskian $W[y_1,y_2](t)$.

The only thing I know is Wronskian is either zero of never a zero. But the Wronskian at $1$ in the exercise is $1\neq0$. How do I evaluate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wronskian $W$ of an equation of the form
$$ y'' + py'+qy=0 $$
satisfies
$$ W'= -pW. $$
In your case, you have
$$ p(t)=\frac{1}{t}, $$
so you have
$$ W(t) = W(1) \exp{\left( -\int_1^t ds/s \right)} = W(1) e^{-\log{t}} = \frac{W(1)}{t}, $$
and $W(1)=1$, as you note, so $W(t)=1/t$.

Comment: Note: that's $W(1)$ we know, $W(0)$ is undefined.

Comment: Ah yes, so it is...

Comment: Hi ! I know it's been some time since you solved this problem, but it's the second time I see the expression $W' = - pW$ and I don't know where it comes from because I didn't achieve to prove it.. could you tell me how you found this equation ?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Start with the equation of evolution of the Wronskian of an ode written in the form $y^{\prime\prime}(t)=p(t)y'(t)+q(t)y(t)$

$$W'(t)=p(t)W(t)=-\frac{1}{t}W(t)$$

That can be obtained by just deriving

$$W(t)=\begin{vmatrix} y_1(t) & y_2(t)\\
y'_1(t) & y'_2(t)
\end{vmatrix}$$

and keep in mind $W(1)=1$